# Publishing a large and complex map to the web

Tags: web-mapping, qgis2web, large-datasets

I have created a complex map of my area and I wish to publish it as an interactive map on the web. The dataset appears to be too large for QGIS2Web to work - the script completes eventually but in loading into the browser it displays the first view but then fails to load the rest of the data, change views, or display the legend, and so it appears to hang. Is there any other plugin or application that I can use?
I would like to publish a map that enables users to zoom in and out, select and deselect layers, and click on the various map items. Much like QGIS itself really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the qgis2web export and the view within a browser faster you have also this possibilities:

point/polygon layers: 
not all layers visible ("layers and groups")
Now the user have the own decision, when he/she want to see a particular layer.

point layers: 
cluster active

polygon layers:
- Minify GeoJSON files (remove unnecessary whitespace from exported GeoJSON to reduce file size) 
- Precision (Simplify geometry to reduce file size), for example "6"
to find under "Export"

I worked with the leaflet export and have tested all possibilities with success.

Edit: You can also do that:
line layers:
If you do not need informations for every line (for examples rivers) you can also union all rivers within a layer (vector-geo..tools-dissolve). Or you can dissolve groups. For example: You have 500 rivers. Now you need a column, name "size". Now every river get the value "1" within size. Then you can use the function union and choose the field "size". Result: You have only one line in your new table in a new file/layer. For qgis2web it is now possible to show the layer faster. In the table you see only one line, but with all rivers!

Comment: Thanks Jürgen I shall investigate these option in more detail. I did make use of some of those you mention, like making some layers not visible to start, and minifying the GeoJSON, but I shall experiment some more.

Comment: No, after looking at all possibilities I still end up with a webmap that does not load. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why do you think eliminating whitespaces could help loading a huge file easier? And does turning off a layer solve a performance problem ?

Comment: @WestCorkPalaeo
Export how? With leaflet? Could you do some screenshots about your setup within qgis2web? 
Alternative to qgis2web: Maybe qgis cloud is a possibilty for you. With qgis cloud you can see your map as within qgis. But I think only for private use.
I have qgis cloud not tested.

Comment: @Iman
" And does turning off a layer solve a performance problem ?" // Sometimes yes: I have created a map with more than 20 layers and more than 6000 POIs. If I activate all layers, the navigation on android browsers are very slow.

Comment: Hi. I have found a bug in my data - it was my fault in defining the symbolology and display features of two layers to concatenate two fields - using a concat statement. This resulted in a line of javascript as follows - switch(String(feature.properties['concat( "DESCRIPT" ,' - ', "UNIT_NAME" )'])) { which clearly exposes the hyphen in the middle and causes a string error of unknown character. So I created a new field which I populated with the concatenated two fields and then used that. That solved that problem and it started to work. But I was still experiencing slow performance and hangups.

Comment: Then I started excluding layers with lots of lines - contours, then roads, then rivers. Now things seem to be performing better.

Comment: And Jurgen - yes leaflet because MapBox GL gavies an error every time - MapBox GL JS error - 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_pop' referenced before assignment 
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\mapboxLayerScripts.py", line 370, in getPopups
    return new_pop
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_pop' referenced before assignment and OpenLayers gives the error IndexError: list index out of range. So leaflet it is.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please read it. Thank you and greetings

Comment: Jürgen - thanks - I have used dissolve and that made a big difference, also, based on your comments I have looked more closely at my data and simplified it - like putting contours into sets 100m, 50m and 10m for example. So the datasets become smaller. As for publishing the leaflet on the web - I think this will be easier outside wordpress limitations. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your map in various levels of generalization. So when you need to show the whole map in the first view, you would be able to show a generalized map which is small rather than reading the whole original big map.

When the user zooms in you should fetch another map which is more detailed but still not the original big map. So by each zoom the user gets closer to the original map while limiting it’s viewing extent more and more in the meantime. Think of it as a pyramid (ESRI calls it pyramid too).

To provide an even better user experience, it is also a good idea to break each of your maps (in your pyramid) into tiles.

To recap, you need to

1. Store different version of your map for different zoom levels
2. Create a tile server for zoom levels that worth it!

There are a lot of libraries and frameworks that help you implement these functionalities. PostGIS for instance has implemented douglas-peucker algorithm to generalize your spatial data if you like to do it yourself. Please take a look at [this](https://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~gisteac/gis_book_abridged/files/ch10.pdf) link for more information on *Generalization*.

QGIS also supports Tile service (as it is a WMTS compliant software), I recommend to take a look at it too.

The best case scenario is that you import your data into PostgreSQL(PostGIS) and create various representation (generalaized maps) then publish each of them into your QGIS Tile server and configure each maps to show up in a particular zoom spectrom.

Comment: OK Thanks I will look at that. The concept is the way I was thinking, to reduce the data density at lower resolution, and increase it as the user zooms in. Or something like that.

Comment: @WestCorkPalaeo Great, if you find the answer useful please accept it.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain?

Comment: Was that me? Did I 'downvote'? How did I do that?

Comment: @WestCorkPalaeo I didn’t mean it was you. I am asking for explanation from someone who actually did the downvote.

Comment: @Iman
I do not think that anybody is a "downvoter", because your solution is very good. My solutions are only meant to complement yours.
There must be many reasons why the export does not work.

Comment: @Jürgen Thanks it was a relief. I was considering deleting my answer.